# Draw vertical line between circles in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want draw a vertical line between circles in my project.
[image]

and these are my codes:

html:

```
    <div id="ways" style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;">
        <div id="row1">
            <div id="col11" class="r1"><canvas id="col111" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col12" class="r1"><canvas id="col112" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col13" class="r1"><canvas id="col113" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
        </div>
        <div id="row2">
            <div id="col21" class="r1"><canvas id="col221" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col22" class="r1"><canvas id="col222" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col23" class="r1"><canvas id="col223" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
        </div>
        <div id="row3">
            <div id="col31" class="r1"><canvas id="col331" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col32" class="r1"><canvas id="col332" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
            <div id="col33" class="r1"><canvas id="col333" width="578" height="200"></canvas></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and theses are js code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('col111');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('col112');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('col113');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();


                var canvas = document.getElementById('col221');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('col222');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();

                var canvas = document.getElementById('col223');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 70;

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 5;
                context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                context.stroke();
```

How I can draw a vertical line between circles? when I tried to do this become this image:
[image]

and this is my js code:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('col221');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(290, -100);
            context.lineTo(290, 80);
            context.stroke();
```

please help for this problem!
thank u!

Comment: It would be useful if you can add the CSS as well.

Comment: Why do you use a diffrent canvas for every circle? (Could can do this easy in 1 canvas)

Comment: It would be better, if possible and if the circles are opaque, to draw the lines *under* the circles, starting at the circles' centers rather than the edge. That way, it will look good even when the circle edge isn't the same color as the connecting line (also you won't need so much maths, and it will work decently for any opaque convex shape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're opting to use multiple canvases but I have implemented a more generic solution in my [fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/o0jhmhkj/1/)

It uses two loops defined as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This makes it more flexible as you can specify the rows and columns in the script. The rest is just knowing what your offsets are!

The code to implement the circle is largely untouched, but the fun is when to draw a line:

```
if (j != cols - 1) {
    // Draw horizontal line
    var hLineX = x + radius;
    var hLineY = y;
    context.moveTo(hLineX, hLineY);
    context.lineTo(hLineX + distance + lineWidth, hLineY);
}
if (i > 0) {
    // Draw vertical line
    var vLineY = y - radius - distance - lineWidth;
    context.moveTo(x, vLineY);
    context.lineTo(x, vLineY + distance + lineWidth);
}
```

All this is saying is that you should draw a horizontal line on every column except for the last one. This works pretty well, even when you have one row by one column. You also want to draw a vertical line when there is more than one row, and offset it so it looks like it joins onto the previous row.

EDIT: Noticed you have different x and y distances, so I modified the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0jhmhkj/2/) to account for this.

Comment: How to set Id for each circle for detect when clicked?

Comment: Why would you need to use this? That doesn't seem particularly practical. I suggest using jQuery or a dedicated svg library such as svg.js as it'll make drawing your circles and adding click events a lot easier. If you wanted to stick with pure JavaScript then you'll need to keep a list of the circle's positions on the canvas, listen for a click event and check if the click position lies within the position of a circle within your list.

Comment: I want when clicked in each circle display a message in circle, but after 3 three click, person must move the text to adjacent circle, Is it have this possibility?

Comment: Of course it's possible! Again, I'd very much look into an SVG library as they easily support click events for vector shapes.

Comment: I want do like this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842157/drag-drop-in-canvas) how I can do it in svg.js? And u have any tutorials about it?