# How to set id for drawn canvas shape?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, shapes

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809152/draw-vertical-line-between-circles-in-canvas) question and I dont know how I can set id for each circles and access them from javascript codes and css codes? (e.g. click)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this by defining click objects when drawing the circles. Inside the loop drawing the circles (ref. the fiddle made by [@MonicaOlejniczak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28810898/1693593)):

```
...

// push circle info as objects:
circles.push({
    id: i + "," + j,    // some ID
    x: x,
    y: y,
    radius: radius
});

...
```

Then:

- add a click handler to canvas
- correct mouse position
- loop through the objects finding if (x,y) is inside the circle:

**Function example:**

```
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    // correct mouse coordinates:
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),  // make x/y relative to canvas
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top,
        i = 0, circle;

    // check which circle:
    while(circle = circles[i++]) {
        context.beginPath();  // we build a path to check with, but not to draw
        context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        if (context.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
            alert("Clicked circle: " + circle.id);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

You can optionally use math instead of the `isPointInPath()`, but the latter is simpler and is fast enough for this purpose.

**[Modified version of the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdLrqv4j/)**

Comment: How I can set Text to any circle just in first click?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an ID on something that has been drawn to a canvas.

> The  element on its own is just a bitmap and does not provide information about any drawn objects.

If you need to interact with the items inside the canvas you need to manually keep a reference to where everything is drawn, or use a system like "object picking" or using the built in [hit regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Hit_regions_and_accessibility#Hit_regions).

Comment: Your purpose is  add canvas for each circle and ....but in that question, how draw a vertical line between circles? and what's your mean from "object picking"?

Comment: No, you shouldn't create different canvases for each circle, but you need to handle each circle yourself. Object picking is a way to work with rendered images, for example http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/